# How to use isql COLUMN Format option

Tags: sybase, isql

I am getting syntax error when I used COLUMN Format in sybase isql

1> column FEEDNAME format ”A30” 
2> go

Incorrect syntax near format.

please advise.

Comment: COLUMN isnt valid in isql that's an Oracle syntax for SQLplus

What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks. I checked Sybase Manual, COLUMN width setting option is not available.

Comment: I overlooked and checked a ctree ISQL Database Manual

Comment: You can use a cast() or convert() in your SQL statement to restrict the size of a column instead e.g. select convert (varchar(30), <column_name>) from mytable. Also check out sp_autoformat that may be an easier solution for you as well - http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36273.1570/html/sprocs/BABHCBIG.htm

Answer (score 0):

COLUMN FORMAT setting is not available in Sybase